# Configuring apache without a super user

Tags: linux, apache, port

I am using Open Suse. I am new to it and web servers (and StackOverFlow too).

There is a apache2 in the etc directory and xyz.xyz.xyz returns "It works!". 
Also xyz.xyz.xyz:5000 currently returns a webpage. I have modified the page and want to host it.

Problem:
How do I configure the apache server to create a port for me?
What files do I need to modify (httpd.conf?)? And will I need super user access?
Thanks

Comment: What port do you want created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSUSE may have a different layout for configuration files, but what you are looking for is a `VirtualHost` directive which is setup to read port 5000. ([Apache docs on `VirtualHost`s](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost))

This may be inside `httpd.conf`, or it may be in another file inside `/etc/apache2` which ends also in `.conf`.  You will find the port 5000 setup looking something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:5000>
  DocumentRoot /path/to/index/dir
  ... Other stuff...
</VirtualHost>
```

To create a VirtualHost which listens on a different port than 5000, just copy the entire `<VirtualHost>...</VirtualHost>` block and change both the port number, and the `DocumentRoot` to point to the place on your filesystem which will hold your other vhost's files.  You will also need a `Listen *:port_number` directive to cause Apache to take over the port.

For example, to add a vhost on 5001, do:

```
# Instructs apache to use this port
Listen *:5001

# Instructs apache to route requests on this port to a specific directory
<VirtualHost *:5001>
  DocumentRoot /path/to/index/dir
  ... Other stuff...
</VirtualHost>
```

You will need to restart Apache after this.

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Note that you **will need superuser access** to do modify the httpd.conf file, and to restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run services below port 1024 you need to have root permissions. As in MIchael's answer, when you run the service on port 5001 you don't need root access